# Is tiled window state not supported on other platforms other than GNOME desktop?

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

I'm trying to implement a cross-platform GTKMM application where the `Gtk::Box` layout changes according to the window state event, that is change `Gtk::Box` layout to either:

- **horizontal layout** - for maximized and floating window state
- or **vertical layout** - for tiled state

My primary OS is Debian GNOME desktop but I'm also testing the code on Windows through VM too. So far my program works well on GNOME desktop but I'm not seeing the same expected behavior on Windows. Screenshots provided for demonstration:

## Debian GNOME

1. ### Floating window (expected output)

[image: Floating window]

2. ### Tiled window (expected output)

[image: tiled window]

## Windows

1. ### Floating window

Same expected output as Linux

2. ### Tiled (not expected output)

[image: tiled on windows]

Below is the example code:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>

using Gtk::Application;
using Gtk::Window;
using Gtk::Box;
using Gtk::Button;
using Gtk::Label;

class WindowStateEvent : public Window
{
    Box    box;
    Button button;
    Label  label;

public:
    WindowStateEvent();

    bool on_window_state_changed(GdkEventWindowState *, Box &);
};

WindowStateEvent::WindowStateEvent()
    : button("Clickable button")
    , label("Hello World!")
{
    set_default_size(320, 240);

    bool expand(true), fill(true);
    box.pack_start(label, expand, fill);
    box.pack_end(button, expand, fill);

    add(box);

    show_all();

    /* GTK doc says something about enabling Gdk::STRUCTURE_MASK to use the below signal
     * Doesn't work or I didn't really get what it's talking about
     */
    //box.add_events(Gdk::STRUCTURE_MASK);
    //add_events(Gdk::STRUCTURE_MASK);
    signal_window_state_event().connect(
                sigc::bind<Box &>(
                    sigc::mem_fun(*this, &WindowStateEvent::on_window_state_changed)
                    , box)
                );
}


bool
WindowStateEvent::on_window_state_changed(GdkEventWindowState *event, Box &box)
{
    bool is_window_tiled = event->new_window_state &
            (Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_RIGHT_TILED | Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_LEFT_TILED);
    bool is_window_maximized = event->new_window_state &
            Gdk::WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED;

    if (is_window_tiled and !is_window_maximized)
        box.set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    else
        box.set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    auto app = Application::create("io.test.window-state-event");

    WindowStateEvent test;

    return app->run(test);
}
```

You can compile the above sample code with:

```sh
g++ -o window-state-event-test main.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

Is the `signal_window_state_event` not cross-platform? Or am I using it wrong?

You can also notice I intentionally commented out the `add_events()` code because even without them the program still runs fine on my primary system. Uncommenting either one of the two comments (either `this` object or `box` object) and building it, I'm still not seeing the same expected output for tiling behavior on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After reporting a bug issue on [gtk development site](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/3103), this feature seems to be supported only on GNOME desktop. Windows support is coming soon.